unity android swipe controller script is correct but not working
I made a game in the style of an endless runner, where the character can swipe left and right and jump in the game. The game works fine in the editor, but when I run it on mobile, I cannot control my character. I think my code is correct:
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        isplay = true;
        player_animator.SetFloat("is_running", 1);
    }

    if (isplay)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + for_Speed * Time.deltaTime);

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        if (current_pos == 0)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(center_pos.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), side_speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (current_pos == 1)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(left_pos.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), side_speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (current_pos == 2)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(right_pos.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), side_speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            if (current_pos == 0)
            {
                current_pos = 1;
            }
            else if (current_pos == 2)
            {
                current_pos = 0;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            if (current_pos == 0)
            {
                current_pos = 2;
            }
            else if (current_pos == 1)
            {
                current_pos = 0;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (onplatform)
            {
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jump_force, ForceMode.Force);
                StartCoroutine(Forward_jump());
            }
        }

#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        if (Input.touchCount == 1) // user is touching the screen with a single touch
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0); // get the touch
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) //check for the first touch
            {
                fp = touch.position;
                lp = touch.position;
            }
            else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) // update the last position based on where they moved
            {
                lp = touch.position;
            }
            else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) //check if the finger is removed from the screen
            {
                lp = touch.position;  //last touch position. Ommitted if you use list

                //Check if drag distance is greater than 20% of the screen height
                if (Mathf.Abs(lp.x - fp.x) > dragDistance || Mathf.Abs(lp.y - fp.y) > dragDistance)
                {//It's a drag
                 //check if the drag is vertical or horizontal
                    if (Mathf.Abs(lp.x - fp.x) > Mathf.Abs(lp.y - fp.y))
                    {   //If the horizontal movement is greater than the vertical movement...
                        if ((lp.x > fp.x))  //If the movement was to the right)
                        {   //Right swipe
                            Debug.Log("Right Swipe");
                            if (current_pos == 0)
                            {
                                current_pos = 2;
                            }
                            else if (current_pos == 1)
                            {
                                current_pos = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {   //Left swipe
                            Debug.Log("Left Swipe");
                            if (current_pos == 0)
                            {
                                current_pos = 1;
                            }
                            else if (current_pos == 2)
                            {
                                current_pos = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {   //the vertical movement is greater than the horizontal movement
                        if (lp.y > fp.y)  //If the movement was up
                        {   //Up swipe
                            Debug.Log("Up Swipe");
                            Forward_jump();
                        }
                        else
                        {   //Down swipe
                            Debug.Log("Down Swipe");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {   //It's a tap as the drag distance is less than 20% of the screen height
                    Debug.Log("Tap");
                }
            }
        }
#endif
    }
}

I built it by just writing the Android codes, but it still didn't work, I think it didn't detect the codes.

you use scripting symbol, so in the editor will use mouse input, and in android device using Input.Touch. There are problems when you use it. Check your code logic again

I solved the problem, please check again, thank you
